# Spring bean is null even though it is beeing populated in another project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I have two projects: A and B.
I create a bean in project A like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConnectorConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "CON")
    public ConnectorRegistry connectorRegistry() {
        return new LocalConnectorRegistry();
    }
}
```

Then in project B I add data to the bean like so:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {
    @Inject
    private ConnectorRegistry connectorRegistry;

    @Bean
    public Connector SomeClass Connector() {
        Connector connector = new BaseConnector(BLA, contextFactory);
        connectorRegistry.register(connector);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

and when I get back to project A I have this class:

```
@Service
@DependsOn("CON")
public class SomeWorker {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectorRegistry connectorRegistry;
```

but the `connectorRegistry` here is null, even though I added data to it and I know, by looking a the spring live bean graph the beans are dependence like so:
`SomeWorker ----> CON <----- SomeClass`

So if `SomeClass` and `SomeWorker` both looks on the same bean, then it shouldn't be null. what am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
In project `A` I call to `SomeWorker` through the `SpringBoot` main class like this, maybe it relates to the problem:

```
/**
 * Application entry point
 */
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(value = "com.other.components")
public class MainApp
        extends MainAppSpringBootApplication {

    public MainApp() {
      super(SomeClass.class);
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder(MainApp.class)
                .initializers(new ZooKeeperPropertiesApplicationContextInitializer())
                .run(args);        
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure SomeWorker is covered in component scan

Comment: @Arjit how can I verify it?

Comment: Can you use @Qualifier("CON") below the autowired bean in SomeWorker class?

Comment: @venkat I can, but in the bean graph I see that they both uses the same bean.

Comment: @Arjit please see edit

Comment: Are you doing a pure spring project or a Spring Boot project?

Comment: @IanLim Spring boot

Comment: I don't see the usage of `SomeWorker` in your main. What does `ZooKeeperPropertiesApplicationContextInitializer` do?

Comment: @TheDragoner: In which package SomeWorker resides?